# merge() increasing the number of rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data sets with common column by the name of "Id", both the data sets have 22099 rows but the number of columns are different. When I use merge() the rows are increased to 15,393,213. Why is this happening. the code is as follows

```
calories_merged_data <- merge(hourlyCalories_merged, hourlyIntensities_merged, by=c('Id'))
```

Example of hourlyCalories_merged

| Id | ActivityHour | Calories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM | 81 |
| 456 | 5/12/2016 06:00:00 AM | 90 |

Example of hourlyIntensities_merged

| Id | Activityhour | TotalIntensity | AverageIntensity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM | 20 | 0.33333 |
| 456 | 5/12/2016 06:00:00 AM | 08 | 0.13333 |
|  |  |  |  |

The data is from https://www.kaggle.com/arashnic/fitbit

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there are duplicates in the ID column, so if there are `n` records with the same ID, each will be merged giving `n^2` records in the merged dataset. You probably need to merge on a combination of variables that is unique to each record.